# cxf with axis, class cast exception. Can I declare my own classloader to avoid

Tags: java, soap, cxf, classloader, axis

Let's start with my exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
```

This problem I believe is due to order of libraries on the tomcat classpath.  I can't change the order.

The recommended solution that I've found from google is to use:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
```

instead of

```
new CxfStubClass(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("wsdl/badVendor.wsdl"),  SERVICE_NAME);
```

The first problem I have is that the wsdl from the vendor doesn't parse with cxf so I've downloaded the wsdl and fixed it.  Using the stub class above I can use the wsdl file via a file on my classpath.  I was unable to find a way to use the 
JaxWSProxyFactory and a wsdl file on the classpath - is this possible?

I could host the file and then reference it via url but that isn't ideal.  It is nice to be able to main method test the soap code without requiring a server up hosting the wsdl.

Let's assume that I host the wsdl.  Now that might work but the soap that I need to process is using a soap header and the only way - that I could find - using cxf to deal with the header was via an interceptor.

```
Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
cxfClient.getInInterceptors().add(myInterceptor);
```

And if I use the JaxWSProxyFactory then the client I am returned doesn't have this same interceptor framework.

I am stuck using soap against an outdated product so while I'd love to avoid all the grief of soap, I can't do that either.

So one thought I had was, can I declare my own classloader and force it to give me the proper class instead of JAXWSProxyHandler?

My other option is to throw everything away and just use axis instead.

Thank you for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I threw everything away and went with Axis.  Axis was pretty terrible too and I had to re-write the stubs it generated so that I could actually get the header properly.